# Prove that if the residual graph doesn't contain a path from $u$ to $v$, then $e=(u,v)$ crosses some minimum cut

Tags: network-flow

Prove: given a flow network $N=(G,s,t,c)$ with a maximum flow $f^*$ and a given edge $e=(u,v)$,
then there's no path from $u$ to $v$ in $N_{f^*}$.

I've seen this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411347/prove-disprove-if-the-residual-graph-g-f-contains-no-path-from-u-to-v-t), but the only answer there is wrong.
I tried building a minimum cut myself, saying $S$ is all the vertices which are accesible from $u$, but I can't prove this is even a valid s-t cut.